# After I release the iOS app, is it possible to change the Deployment Target from iOS8 to iOS7?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-app

I'm developing an iOS app.
A certain app has been released in the App Store in the Deployment TargetiOS8.

With additional development it will lower the Deployment Target to iOS7.
I want to assume that the application API of is compatible with all iOS7.

The app you change the Deployment Target from iOS8 to iOS7, registered to iTunes Connect, Will it be able to release to the App Store?

Answer (score 5):

Ya you can do this. in the new release you can change the minimum deployment and you can upload the new build in appstore, your app will surely approve from apple.

Comment: Anbu.Karthik. Thank you.
In iTunes Connect, I was worried that there is something special restriction.
Was one peace of mind. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TakeshiSato - happy to hear this bro , if my answer is useful please upvote the answer