# Is it possible to submit the ios app with upgarde version from 7.1 to 8( and above ) to itunes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm developing an iOS app. A certain app has been released in the App Store with the Deployment Target iOS7.
I am introducing some new feature to my app which support IOS8. So want to change my App Deployment Target to IOS8.

So i have to change baseSDK or not? or what type of changes i have to make in my app.
i want to know  will it be able to release to the App Store?

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159152/after-i-release-the-ios-app-is-it-possible-to-change-the-deployment-target-from) from where i get some idea but still not clear .

Comment: Yes you can change app development target and then change your app version and upload to app store. it will work as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) Base SDK refers to the newest version of iOS that is capable of running your app. To check which base SDK you are building your app against, simply open your project file in Xcode and check the setting under Build Settings -> Architecture(...)

2) Deployment Target refers to the oldest version of iOS that is capable of running your project. To change your deployment target, open up your project file in Xcode and check the setting under Build Settings -> Deployment(...)

3) The base SDK is what you build your app against (i.e. include and library files and frameworks). It doesn't affect the deployment target, except that base SDK >= Deployment Target.

4) So you just need to change your app Deployment Target and then change your app Version and Build and then upload the app on app store.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change the minimum deployment target(as you mentioned iOS 8 to current version),
>   Update app version(as you mentioned 8.0) & Change build
>   version too(else you will get message something like from build already exist while uploading).

Finally generate IPA file for App Distribution. Move .ipa file to iTunes using App Loader or Xcode(via selecting upload to app store option).

In iTunes select option to add version which is shown in left side.Now fill meta data of an app. Once your build reviewed were done successfully. You can able to see in Build selection in iTunes.